# Places to iron clothes in Leiden or Amsterdam

Tags: netherlands, services, clothing

I am in Leiden, as a new expat.

Please, is there any place to iron my clothes? I have an important meeting and i would like to iron my suit.

If Leiden doesn't have such a place, where in Amsterdam can I do that?

The thing is, I need to know if this place available on Saturdays and Sundays. I will arrive on Saturday morning and I need the suit ready by Sunday night at the latest.

It may seem a silly question, but it is necessary for me. I will have an 18-hours flight and if Leiden doesn't have such a place, nor Amsterdam (open during  weekends) I do that in my country :(

Comment: Buy a cheap iron and ironing board then do it at home?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, I prefer to do it in a professional place, I am not good

Comment: And welcome to Leiden, it's a nice place (I lived there for 20 years).

Comment: If you iron the suit and then take an eighteen hour flight, won't the suit be wrinkled by the end of the flight?

Comment: @DJClayworth I often hang the jacket to the seat in front of me (there are little “hooks” for that). Still not ideal, though.

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

- Look for a dry cleaner (that's called *stomerij* in Dutch). Most will be open on Saturday and closed on Sunday (some are even open on Sunday but the one I know is in Rotterdam…) Regular service is not same-day however, usually more like 2 or 3. I assume some express service might be available for a premium in some places but I never needed it so I am not able to provide additional info on that.
- Buy an iron and ironing board. Not ideal for a suit (see comments) but possibly a back-up solution. Personally I need an iron (for shirts, not suits) regularly but of course if you never ever iron your clothes, it will feel like a waste of money. You should find some in many household items and electronics store, some of which might even be opened on Sunday (depends on the city and on the store, you need to look it up). For example: Blokker, MediaMarkt, BCC.
- Clean and iron your suit wherever you are before (possibly using hotel service if you're staying at an hotel) and take it with you. You should not fold it but there are different ways to keep it in a decent state during travel: rolling it, hanging it, wearing it (yes, that's usually better than folding, although 18 hours is a bit long!)

Comment: Hi Gala, thanks for answering. *Regular service is not same-day* I believe this is for cleaning and ironing, not just ironing. *Buy an iron and ironing board* that's, unfortunately, never an option for me, not just I've never used it, but suites and jackets are, in my opinion, hard stuff to iron even for an experienced person. *Clean and iron your suit wherever you are before* well I am thinking of actually wearing it, but that is the last case. If no other options, I will iron it and take it with me but i hope we find a working stomerij that finishes all the stuff in Saturday,

Comment: The first one I clicked on after a Google search was http://www.stomerijvanaalst.nl/diensten-en.html , they do have same day service (bring in the morning, collect in the afternoon). There must be more. Do you arrive early on saturday?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I arrive friday night actually

Comment: @朝陽陽菜 Possibly, I usually use their services for cleaning and in my experience suits don't need to be ironed more frequently than they need to be cleaned so I actually never needed to iron a suit either.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Good tip. Of course, it might be a self-serving exaggeration but note that the website actually says "Wij zijn de enige stomerij in Leiden waarbij je in de ochtend brengt en eind van de middag ophaalt."

Comment: Note that usually you don't *iron* your suit but you *press* it using steam. But the stomerij will know that. It's another reason to use the stomerij and not do it yourself - you'd have to be good at ironing to get the result of pressing (which includes a longer lifetime for your suit).

Answer (score 3):

That's a service offered by dry cleaners, usually after cleaning your suit (but I guess that only ironing already clean clothes is also possible, have never done that). That kind of store is called a **stomerij** in Dutch. They are usually open on Saturdays, but will definitely be **closed on Sundays**. There will be several in all cities.

A search for "stomerij leiden" on Google Maps shows about 15, most of them will be able to help you for a few euro.

That said, if it were me this is not the sort of thing I would want to be doing after an 18 hour flight into a new country.